# Trying to get xml from url but getting FATAL ERROR: main

Tags: java, android, xml, fatal-error

Iam a beginner programing in android and java so excuse me if the code is wrong. I'm just trying to get some xml from a url and then display it in logcat but i keep getting the same errors.

Here is the log:

```
01-01 19:49:38.065: E/Trace(6471): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-01 19:49:38.225: D/AndroidRuntime(6471): Shutting down VM
01-01 19:49:38.225: W/dalvikvm(6471): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c72300)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alexisdelatorre.helloxml/com.alexisdelatorre.helloxml.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at com.alexisdelatorre.helloxml.JavaXmlTutorial.getXmlFromUrl(JavaXmlTutorial.java:64)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at com.alexisdelatorre.helloxml.JavaXmlTutorial.<init>(JavaXmlTutorial.java:31)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at com.alexisdelatorre.helloxml.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-01 19:49:38.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6471):     ... 11 more
```

And the code:

```
package com.alexisdelatorre.helloxml;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaXmlTutorial {

    public JavaXmlTutorial() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{


        String xmlFromUrl = getXmlFromUrl("http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml");

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(new StringReader (xmlFromUrl));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
         if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
             Log.d(TAGS.DEBUG, "start document");
         } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
             Log.d(TAGS.DEBUG, "end document");
         } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
             Log.d(TAGS.DEBUG,"Start tag "+xpp.getName());
         } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
             Log.d(TAGS.DEBUG,"End tag "+xpp.getName());
         } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
             Log.d(TAGS.DEBUG,"Text "+xpp.getText());
         }
         eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    }

    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }


}
```

Comment: Try to run your `JavaXmlTutorial` in `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make `HTTP` requests on the main thread, it would cause the `UI` to freeze up. So it throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception. You need to do it in an `AsyncTask` or another `Thread`.

Check out [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

```
class SynchTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
          protected void onPreExecute()
          {           super.onPreExecute();
                    //display progressdialog.
          } 

           protected void doInBackground(Void ...params)
          {  
                //http request. do not update ui here
                  JavaXmlTutorial parse=new JavaXmlTutorial();
                 return null;
          } 
          protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
          {     
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    //dismiss progressdialog.
                    //update ui
          } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but, can you give me an example? or an url?

Comment: oh, i think that i have to do some research if i want to mess with xml. well, thank you, you realy helped me a lot.

Comment: You're Welcome. :) Happy New Year :) @Alxs24

Comment: @Alxs24 to be clear, this has *nothing* to do with xml

Comment: xD thank you, and happy new year to everyone